# Can I keep mongodb connected in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

Is there any way to connect mongodb and use it anywhere? When ever I want to use mongodb I have to verbosely type `$m= new Mongo;`.I'm wondering whether repeatedly connecting could affect performance.

Comment: Those 14 characters sure _are_ verbose...

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL well, my key point is performance issue. If repeatedly connecting doesn't affect performance why there's mysql_pconnect in mysql to keep connection alive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would have mattered for MongoDb < 1.2, but after that persistant connections are the default.
All language drivers for MongoDb smartly manage connection pools internally, so you are safe in using them with default behaviour.
Due to connection pooling, whenever you create a `new Mongo()` , it selects an established connection from the connection pool, or reconnects if there isn't any.

Excerpts from :
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.connecting.php

```
In 1.2.0+, connections are always persistent and managed 
automatically by the driver.
```

> "Connection Pooling (version 1.2.0+)
>
> Creating connections is one of the most heavyweight things that the
>   driver does. It can take hundreds of milliseconds to set up a
>   connection correctly, even on a fast network. Thus, the driver tries
>   to minimize the number of new connections created by reusing
>   connections from a pool.
>
> When a user creates a new instance of Mongo, all necessary connections
>   will be taken from their pools (replica sets may require multple
>   connections, one for each member of the set). When the Mongo instance
>   goes out of scope, the connections will be returned to the pool. When
>   the PHP process exits, all connections in the pools will be closed. "

You can try this using a test php script, and observing `mongostat` to see maximum  connections that form.

Answer (score 1):

```
private $m;
private function getMongo() {
    if ($this->m) return $this->m;
    return $this->m = new Mongo();
}
```

The technique is called `memoization`. Now everywhere you would normally create a new mongo instance, call this function instead, and it will give you the existing connection rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Not quite. A Singleton would store $m in the Mongo class, and Mongo would have no public constructor